# PowerShell execution policy

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am running an EXE file from a mapped drive and supplying a few arguments while running it (it is an update/hotfix). However, the `/q` or silent operation switch is not honored when the EXE file is run from the mapped network drive. If the same EXE file is copied over locally, it works fine.

I am running

```
Start-Process -Filepath "z:\abc.exe" -ArgumentList '/quiet /norestart' -Wait
```

This pops up a dialog box to confirm my action, but I want to suppress it.

If I copy abc.exe locally and run,

```
Start-Process -Filepath "c:\abc.exe" -ArgumentList '/quiet /norestart' -Wait
```

it just works fine.

I checked *Execution* policy and it is set to *Unrestricted*. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The dialog may be a security warning that you are installing something over the network and not related to the quiet install of the EXE file.

Comment: +1 Powershell's execution policy has no influence on applications

Comment: It's not Powershell's execution policy, but on some computer PowerShell responds the same as the Explorer Shell when it runs scripts from a UNC path: “while scripts from the internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your computer. Do you want to run ?”

Comment: @JPBlanc - Did you read my answer at all? I have given almost the same answer as you have now ( except I didn't say how to fix it ). Also note my last line which says this has **nothing** to do with Execution Policy in Powershell. If you had downvoted my answer, I ask you to take it back.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the problem when I added a network path (letter or [UNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention) - I don't remember) to `$env:PSModulePath`. Each time I wanted to load a module from the network, a warning message appeared. It may be the same thing if you want to `. source` a PS1 file from a network drive in the user's profile.

**It was coming from an Internet Explorer policy**: Some machines are configured to treat UNC paths as the same security zone as the Internet (as opposed to the intranet.) This is Internet Explorer’s "Enhanced Security Configuration". In this case, PowerShell responds the same as the [Windows Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer) shell when it runs scripts from a UNC path:

> “while scripts from the Internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your computer. Do you want to run <script>?”

One way to fix this is by adding the source server to Internet Explorer’s Trusted Sites, or [changing the “UncAsIntranet” configuration property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457150.aspx).

**You can also have a look to this**: The EXE files coming from a download are locked.

And [NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) keeps track of that in the file extended attribute. Look in the properties of the EXE file (sorry, in French. Here the 'Débloquer' button is the 'Unlock' button):

[image]

Comment: I do not see "Unlock" button on this exe. Also I did not get when you said:"It may be the same thing if you want to . source a PS1 file from a network drive in the users profile." 
what does it mean by: "if you want to .source a PS1 from n/w drive in users profile"?

Comment: [Dot sourcing a script](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx#ECAA) allow you to load _vars, functions_ from a PS1 file in the current session. Do you try to create **UncAsIntranet** key ?